# Is there any command to go to the end (or beginning) of a Ruby block using vim

Tags: ruby, vim

Is there a way to go the end of a Ruby block using vim? For example

```
module SomeModule

   # <Supposing that the cursor is HERE>
  def some_method
  end

end
```

I want to go from where the cursor is, to the end of the block with one command, is that possible?

I've read [this documentation](http://vim.runpaint.org/navigation/navigating-source-code/), but it doesn't seem to work on .rb files, I've read in some places that it only works on C (haven't tried though).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not only C, but as far as I'm aware, only with C-like syntax, (C, C++, java, C#, etc), ie. `{}` marking code blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is an official package at [rubyforge](http://rubyforge.org/frs/shownotes.php?group_id=16&release_id=11557) that has some support for this:

> The Ruby ftplugin now includes Ruby specific implementations for the [[, ]],
>   [], ][, [m, ]m, [M, and ]M normal mode commands.  These allow you to move to
>   move quickly between module, class and method declarations.

**Edit**:  The README says that these files are included in the default VIM distro but they don't work for me in GVIM on Windows, '{' and '}' seem to work on vim under Linux

Answer (score 3):

```
%
```

It works with most languages where it's clear that your cursor is on or near a block marker.

Comment: That would work if and only if the cursor is either on "module SomeModule" or the "end" of that block. Not when the cursor is inside it.

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my installation of Vim7.2. On both def and module.

Comment: Of course, the other block navigation commands should also work. If they're not working, check your Ruby ftplugin.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm working on a macvim environment... probably the ftplugin is outdated, I'll check this out.

Comment: On nvim (on mac) it also does not work out of the box - worked after installing https://github.com/tpope/vim-endwise .

Answer (score -1):

Try this - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=303   (Disclaimer: untested)